# Using Drupal's UserManager to clean up user in Behat test

Tags: php, drupal, bdd, behat

I'm new to Behat and trying to get this test working correctly with Behat version 3.4.3.

```
001 Scenario: Staff users can create accounts             # features/user.feature:9
  And I register "byron@poetsforever.com" for cleanup # features/user.feature:21
    16384: Interacting directly with the RawDrupalContext::$users property has been deprecated.
    Use RawDrupalContext::getUserManager->getUsers() instead. in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/drupal/drupal-extension/src/Drupal/DrupalExtension/Context/RawDrupalContext.php line 152
```

And here is what I believe to be the offending step in my FeatureContext.php:

```
/**
 * @When I register :email for cleanup
 */


public function registerUserByEmailForCleanup($email) {
    // User must exist or this will throw an error.
    $user = $this->userLoadByEmail($email);
    $this->users[$user->name] = $user;
  }
```

Any pointers on how to convert this to update the step to fix the deprecation error would be much appreciated, or ideas on how to get Behat to ignore the error and keep running. Have had no luck so far. Thanks!

Comment: If your context is extending `RawDrupalContext` then that warning is caused by `$this->users[$user->name] = $user;`. 
Is your `FeatureContext` extending `RawDrupalContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all you have to do is to replace

```
$this->users[$user->name] = $user;
```

with

```
$this->getUserManager()->addUser($user);
```

At least this is what seems logical to me after reading through [RawDrupalContext.php](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/blob/master/src/Drupal/DrupalExtension/Context/RawDrupalContext.php).

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the exact same issue with a form allowing for manual user creation. It's very unclear how behat handles entities, but it ultimately is using a `\stdClass` and not the `User` class you would expect:

Here's the code & gherkin syntax we used to accomplish:

```
 /**
   * Create a user and register with Behat for cleanup.
   *
   * Let behat know we manually created a user so it can clean it up in its
   * AfterScenario hook.
   *
   * @TODO: Is there no existing method for this step??
   *
   * @Then I have manually created :username
   */
  public function manuallyCreatedUser($username) {
    $user = user_load_by_name($username);
    if ($user) {
      $user_obj = (object) array(
        'name' => $username,
        'uid' => $user->id(),
        'pass' => '',
        'mail' => $user->getEmail(),
        'role' => implode(",", $user->getRoles()),
      );
      $this->users[$username] = $user_obj;
    }
  }
```

There's a few things going on here:

- Behat is not using a `User` object to keep track, but instead a `\stdClass` with properties.
- This simply creates the object behat is expecting
- Came to this solution by following along `RawDrupalContext` and ultimately `Drupal8::userDelete()`